# Writing function with `while` failed

Tags: r, function, indexing, while-loop

I am writing codes about changing decimal numbers to binary numbers.

This is my code with `while` and it worked.

```
i <- 1
binary_vec <- rep(0, 5)
x <- 15
while (i <= 5) {
  binary_vec[i] <- x %% 2
  x <- x %/% 2
  i <- i + 1
}
binary_vec
```

However, I tried to write this code as a function and it failed.

```
i <- 1
decimal_to_binary <- function(x) {
  binary_vec <- rep(0, 5)
  while (i <= 5) {
    binary_vec[i] <- x %% 2
    x <- x %/% 2
    i <- i + 1
  }
}
decimal_to_binary(22)
binary_vec
```

If I type `decimal_to_binary(22)`, the result of `binary_vec` is supposed to be `01101` but it is not.

I want to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 99% of the way there! Move `i` inside the function and return the `binary_vec` object:

```
decimal_to_binary <- function(x) {
  i <- 1
  binary_vec <- rep(0, 5)
  while (i <= 5) {
    binary_vec[i] <- x %% 2
    x <- x %/% 2
    i <- i + 1
  }
  binary_vec
}
decimal_to_binary(22)
```

Edits for a `for` loop version:

```
decimal_to_binary_for <- function(x, n=5) {
  binary_vec <- NULL
  for (i in 1:n) {
    binary_vec[i] <- x %% 2
    x <- x %/% 2
  }
  binary_vec
}
decimal_to_binary_for(22)
# [1] 0 1 1 0 1
decimal_to_binary_for(512, n=12)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: thanks. I finally solved this problem. :) Hope you have a nice day.